# What do hyphens signify in Db2 for i query results?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I want to filter out the rows containing dashes in the following query.  The `PRMWT` column is `DECIMAL (9, 3)`.

Query

```
SELECT
    PPA#,
    PRMWT
FROM FUTMODS.SCPMSTQ
WHERE PPA# = '20829161'
```

Result

```
PPA#        PRMWT
20829161    53.513
20829161    -
20829161    -
20829161    -
20829161    -
20829161    -
```

If I add the condition `AND PRMWT IS NOT NULL`, the result is the same and I get this warning:

> SQL State: 01565 Vendor Code: 802 Message: [SQL0802] Data conversion
> or data mapping error. Cause . . . . . :   Error type 6 has occurred.
> Error types and their meanings are: 1 -- Arithmetic overflow. 2 --
> Floating point overflow. 3 -- Floating point underflow. 4 -- Floating
> point conversion error. 5 -- Not an exact result. 6 -- Numeric data
> that is not valid. 7 -- Double-byte character set (DBCS) or UTF-8 data
> that is not valid. 8 -- Division by zero. 9 -- Hash value cannot be
> computed for the requested query. 10 -- User-defined function returned
> a mapping error. 11 -- Not valid length found in a varying-length
> column returned from an array result set. 12 -- Result of a
> concatenation operation on a varying-length field exceeded the maximum
> allowed length of the result type. If the error occurred when
> assigning a value to a host variable of a FETCH, embedded SELECT, SET,
> or VALUES INTO statement, the host variable name is *N and the
> relative position of the host variable in the INTO clause is 2. If the
> host variable name is *N, the error occurred when attempting to
> resolve a search condition. If more than one data mapping error
> occurred, this is a description of the first error that occurred.  For
> a description of any other data mapping errors, see the previously
> listed messages in the job log. Recovery  . . . :   The error was
> caused by data that was not valid or that was too large.  Look at the
> previously listed messages in the job log (DSPJOBLOG command) or press
> F10 (Display messages in job log) on this display to determine what
> row and columns were involved in the error.  Correct the data and then
> try the request again.

Upon closer inspection, I see the column has `Nullable = No`.  Ok, but then why does it have something non-numeric in it (the hyphen)?

I also tried `PRMWT > 0`, `PRMWT > 0.0`, `PRMWT > '000000.000'`, `PRMWT != '-'`, `PRMWT != ''`, `PRMWT = CAST(0.0 AS DECIMAL(9,3))`, `CAST(PRMWT AS FLOAT) > 0.0`, etc.

I'm lost.  What the heck does a hyphen signify in this godforsaken DB engine and how do I operate on it?  The OS is version 7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `hex` function to look for decimal data errors in the `PRMWT` field:

```
SELECT  PPA#, hex(PRMWT) hex_prmwt
FROM FUTMODS.SCPMSTQ
WHERE PPA# = '20829161'
```

to correct the bad data you can test for specific hex values and use `SQL UPDATE` to set the field to 0.

```
update FUTMODS.SCPMSTQ
set    PRMWT = 0
where  hex(PRMWT) = '404040'
```

Here is a good article: https://www.itjungle.com/2013/08/07/fhg080713-story02/

Comment: Well, someone cleaned up the bad data before I got the chance to try this, but I assume this answer would have worked and thus accepted it.  It's so strange to me that the database permits garbage data in the first place, but here we are.

Comment: SQL does not permit the bad data. But RPG and record i/o does.  The system has a long legacy. Applications were written which supported large number of users running on hardware with a small fraction of the performance available today. Quite remarkable actually, what the business apps of the past were able to do.

Comment: More specifically, data in legacy DDS defined physical files is validated on READ.  Whereas the data in an SQL DDL defined table is validated on WRITE.

Comment: Also once the OP gets updated to a more recent version of the OS, the  [SYSTOOLS.VALIDATE_DATA()](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6174171) could be used.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for elaborating, both of you.  At my company, the data writing is done almost entirely outside of SQL, which aligns with your comments.

Comment: @MarredCheese It doesn't actually matter which is used to WRITE the data, what matters is what is used to define the TABLES (aka files).

Comment: @Charles Oh, I see.  Could I accidentally put bad data in such a table (one that was not defined via SQL) via "normal" SQL statements?  Or would it only come up if I did something deliberately off the beaten path like `UPDATE t SET c = HEX(...) ...`?

Comment: Charles is correct, but when using SQL to insert a record into the database, I don't believe that there is a way to coerce SQL to insert bad data, even if the tables are DDS defined. With RPG, you have to use an old internally defined table or data structure to do it but if you are using the data structure, you can't access any of the numeric fields which contain non-numeric characters, or that will throw an error. With externally defined files, the compiler is pretty good at preventing bad data in the table in most cases.