# Incorrect data population issue in numeric field in PF in AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a PF in DB2 which is showing a ++++ sign, the column value is defined as numeric 3 lengths.

[image]

I have tried ABS, ABSVAL, ROUND, TRUNCATE, REPLACE, and CHAR biffs on this column but none of them seems to show me what this ++++ actually is. Because of this ++++ sign, I cannot insert any data on this row, thereby stopping anything from being inserted after this row.

If possible, I am looking to remove this ++++ sign incorrect data from the file.

I shall be grateful for any help/guidance.

Comment: Did you try to use the hex() function on the column?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy yes, this is what it shows, 40 is for blanks i guess, but  I am still wondering what that + means 

VALUE
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0 
404040 
404040 
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0 
F0F0F0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jmarkmurphy and @charles for your thoughtful inputs, I have found my solution in both your suggestions.

I have tried to summarize the issue for future readers as below.

So apparently the  ++++ sign or - sign is DB2's way of showing corrupt data. The possible reason for existence of such a data could be during data transmission between two systems, or improper handling of decimal data error done by the operator.

However, I have researched a lot on this but there is no way we can see what this ++++ or - sign actually holds.

But still just to our eyes satisfaction, as recommended by @jmarkmurphy
use the hex() function on the column we can see something like

[image]

notice that the hex value for ++++ is 404040, which represents @ sign in ascii table

Reference fore HEx to ascii conversion -

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ascii-table-hex-to-ascii-value-character-code-chart-2/

[image]

The only possible way to deal with such corrupt data is to isolate them and remove them. thanks to @charles for this url

[What do hyphens signify in Db2 for i query results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100507/what-do-hyphens-signify-in-db2-for-i-query-results)

Comment: These are EBCDIC spaces. I will write an answer that explains what is happening.

Comment: That 40 is an EBCDIC space. the explaination is too much for a comment. I would write a full explaination if @Charles didn't close it.